# I want to move the screen with a button in React Native

Tags: react-native, navigation

I want to go to another screen by pressing the image button on the screen, but I don't know how. I am a complete beginner.
How can I go to the next page?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, TouchableOpacity,Image,Alert } from 'react-native';

import {} from 'react-navigation';

const ButtonScreen = props => {
    const content = (
        <View style= {[styles.button]}>
            <Image source={require('../assets/icon/룰렛.png')} style={{
            transform: [{scale: 0.37}],
        }}
                />
        </View>
    )

    return (
    <TouchableOpacity  onPress={() => {
        Alert.alert('빨리');
      }}

    >{content}</TouchableOpacity>
    )
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create ({
    button: {
        top: 60,
        flexDirection: 'row',
        alignItems: 'center',
        height: '30%',
        width: '100%',
    },
})

export default ButtonScreen;
```

Comment: you can use props.navigation.navigate('yourNextScreen'). To do that, you need to configure your navigation stack.

Answer (score 0):

for navigation in react-native there are various libraries. react-navigation, react-native-router-flux, react-native-navigation(wix) are the ways you can use for navigation.

[react-navigation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/getting-started) is the famous one that currently has V5.x following by thorough documentation. It uses JavaScript codes for navigation and I assume you installed this library.

the [react-native-router-flux](https://github.com/aksonov/react-native-router-flux) use react-navigation V4.x and it really looks like [react-router-dom](https://reactrouter.com/web/guides/quick-start) in React-js. However I strongly suggest to not using that due to problems regarding performance.

[react-native-navigation(wix)](https://wix.github.io/react-native-navigation/docs/before-you-start/) has the highest performance because it uses native codes for navigation. however it has poor document and it is really difficult for beginners to use.

In order to use the current version of react-navigation the first step you need to do is the installation of requirement then you need to have separate file for defining your routes. Lets assume you have two screens. the file looks like the following code:

```
import React from 'react';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
import Screen1 from 'the path of Screen1'
import Screen2 from ' the path of Screen2'

const Stack = createStackNavigator();

function Navigation() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="Home">
        <Stack.Screen name="Screen1" component={Screen1} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Screen2" component={Screen2} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}

export default Navigation
```

then you need to import this file on your index file.

```
import Navigation from "the path of Navigation";

AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName, () => Navigation);
```

if you are at ButtonScreen and you want to go on Screen2 you need the following code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, TouchableOpacity,Image,Alert } from 'react-native';
const ButtonScreen = props => {
    const content = (
        <View style= {[styles.button]}>
            <Image source={require('../assets/icon/룰렛.png')} style={{
            transform: [{scale: 0.37}],
        }}
                />
        </View>
    )

    return (
    <TouchableOpacity  onPress={() => props.navigation.navigate("Screen2")}

    >{content}</TouchableOpacity>
    )
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create ({
    button: {
        top: 60,
        flexDirection: 'row',
        alignItems: 'center',
        height: '30%',
        width: '100%',
    },
})

export default ButtonScreen;
```

this is the easiest way to navigate and I recommend you to read [the document](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/getting-started)

Comment: Then, where should I write the first code? The second code is...

import {AppRegistry} from 'react-native';
import App from './screens/App';
import {name as appName} from './app.json';

AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName, () => App);

It is.

Should I change it to the second code you wrote here?

Comment: Oh, and thank you so much for your kind reply!

Comment: Currently, I made and used the 1st code you wrote me in a js file called stackscreen, and the 2nd code was written in a file called index.js. The third file was also put on the buttonscreen. '[Error: undefined Unable to resolve module ./Button from D:\react native\RNTabNavigator\index.

Comment: when you initiate react-native app there are some boiler plate you can see the App and index file in the root of your project. consider App.js as your navigation and do the rest of it